# Zero disk space, not logging me in

Tags: disk, disk-usage

I tried to recover my external HDD data as it got corrupted, and I succeeded, but now those folders are in primary memory with no permissions and my system booting saying disk space 0. I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Login screen takes password and then endless wait...

What should I do?

Comment: You will have enter recovery mode and move the files back to your external HDD.

Comment: Thanks George, I Tried that, but no space in corrupted HDD, tried mv -T /src  /dev/mnt, error msgs for each files-no space, is there any command to delete the locked Folders through Recovery mode?

Comment: Yes just use `rm -rf` to do so now that it's mounted

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> Will take you to the console login. Make some space from the console and reboot, you will be able to use the graphic environment.

You will need to move or remove files and folders. If you are not familiar with the command line, type:

```
man rm
man mv
```

`df -h` shows the disk space and `du -sh afolder/*` the space taken by files inside `afolder`

Comment: Almost all space is captured by locked folders which were recovered from corrupted external HDD, whatever i try with tbose folders, system denies because of the permission...access denied. Only i succeeded in removing the read only files but that did not create any considerable space. Anyways, thanks for the help.

Comment: @RoshanB use sudo, i.e. `sudo rm -rf afilethatwilldeleteforever` if you still have problems, try `chmod` and `chown` to change the permissions of the files.